# Open source and independent ARM and RISC-V assemblers

Tags: assembly, arm, open-source, intel, riscv

I'm creating a project and I need INTEL, ARM and RISC-V assemblers that are independent and run on Windows and Linux. For the INTEL architecture, I found the NASM assembler, it fulfills all my requirements, however I cannot find the assemblers for ARM and RISC-V.

The only ARM and RISC-V assemblers I found were from GNU. But to install it you need the entire GNU toolchain, which doesn't seem like a good idea. Besides this toolchain is not available on Windows.

Are there any open source, standalone ARM and RISC-V assemblers available outside of NASM (NASM style would just be a standalone assembler and nothing else)?

Edit1: GNU/MinGW IS NOT INDEPENDENT, it comes with a bunch of other features, like C and C++ linker and compiler, unlike NASM. Also, as far as I know, MinGW does not have the ARM and/or RISC-V assembler, but only the INTEL assembler, which is not useful for me, since I already use NASM.

Edit2: Analyzing has rather gnu toolchain for ARM and RISC-V for Windows, however is there any application that is only an assembler for ARM and RISC-V? I do not want a gnu and clang, but rather just an assembler (an example would be the NASM, which is for INTEL).

Comment: I think to use gas (the GNU assembler) you just need binutils.

Comment: The GNU binutils are available for Windows (built with MinGW).  They can even produce PE executables as required by Windows.

Comment: example [riscv toolchain for windows](https://gnutoolchains.com/risc-v/)

Comment: ARM has been around for a long time, there's a lot of stuff for it, including a Microsoft assembler. RISC-V not so much, the gnu thing seems to be the main one.

Comment: You can run [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/) on windows, so full linux, use linux toolchain there.  Of course that will build linux binaries.

Comment: pre-built binutils or full toolchains if you cant find binutils are available in more places than you have time to mess with.

Comment: As other have said even before your last edit, you can install Binutils and just get `as` and `ld`, not `gcc`.  (`clang` is a separate package; if you wanted an LLVM-based tool you would need the full `clang` I think; but one `clang` binary can target multiple architectures, like `clang -target riscv32 -c foo.s` or `clang -target arm -c bar.s` both work on my x86-64 Linux desktop).  Binutils comes with other tools like `objdump` and `objcopy`, so you might want to isolate just the GNU assembler, but that's just a matter of packaging.

Comment: On WSL2 Ubuntu, you can run `apt-get install binutils-arm-none-eabi binutils-riscv64-unknown-elf` and you have both.  Mingw-binutils is minimal assemblers.  As Windows is traditionally developed on x86, it will have many assemblers.  ARM and risc-v will be cross assemblers.  An assembler by itself is not a tool.  You need a linker as well.  I don't think telling people you don't want the only thing available is a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from what I realized apparently there is no open source project that focuses exclusively on an ARM assembler and RISC-V. But there are 4 solutions to my problem.

(1): Use WSL2 on Windows, and on Linux use GNU or LLVM. Because they have several tools, such as multi-platform assemblers, in the case of ARM and RISC-V. This solution is especially useful if you are compiling for Linux using a Windows

(2): Using LLVM, more specifically clang, it can compile RISC-V and ARM assembly codes. These options are used for this:

> riscv32 --> `clang -target riscv32 -c foo.s`

> riscv64 --> `clang -target riscv64 -c foo.s`

> arm32 --> `clang -target arm -c foo.s`

> arm64 --> `clang -target arm64 -c foo.s`

(3): Using GNU, in windows using https://gnutoolchains.com/, and on Linux using apt or similar tools to download the ARM and RISC-V toolchains, and in them comes assemblers.

(4): Using FASMG and FASMARM.

> FASMG: https://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=19389

> FASMARM: https://arm.flatassembler.net/

(Extra for Windows): Microsoft itself provides tools such as assemblers to use, in Windows, such as MASM for INTEL and ARMASM for ARM. Because you don't have Windows for RISC-V yet, you don't have a Microsoft RISCVASM.

> MASM --> (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/masm-for-x64-ml64-exe?view=msvc-170)

> ARMASM --> (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/arm/arm-assembler-reference?view=msvc-170)